# Digital clock in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The code is for making a digital clock, what's the use of putting a `setTimeout` function in the `showTime` function and what is the use of setting both the `textcontent` and `Innertext`

```js
function showTime(){
var date = new Date();
var h = date.getHours();// 0 - 23
var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
var session = "AM";

if(h == 0){
    h = 12;
}

if(h > 12){
    h = h - 12;
    session = "PM";
}

h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;

setTimeout(showTime, 1000);

}

showTime();
```

```html
<div id="MyClockDisplay" class="clock"></div>
```

Comment: I have added inner text

Comment: Do you know what `setTimeout` does? If so, what do you not understand about it? If not, why have you not read documentation about it?

Comment: *"what is the use of setting both the textcontent and Innertext"* None. Use one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setTimeout` at the bottom of `showTime` so that each call of `showTime` will queue up the function to run again in 1 second - which, when run, will queue the function again after another second, and so on. Having a function recursively call itself with `setTimeout` is an alternative to using `setInterval`.

`textContent` is generally preferable over `innerText` - see [The poor, misunderstood innerText](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/), though if you're just assigning rather than getting, it doesn't matter much. `innerHTML` isn't appropriate here because you're assigning *text*, not *HTML markup*.

Using `setInterval` rather than a recursive `setTimeout` would look like this, accomplishing the exact same thing:

```js
function showTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
  var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
  var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
  var session = "AM";

  if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
  }

  if (h > 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    session = "PM";
  }

  h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
  m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

  var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
  document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
  document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;
}

showTime();
setInterval(showTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="MyClockDisplay" class="clock"></div>
```

Comment: @certainperformance The time doesn't change when settimeout is not in it, it only changes when settimeout is in it, please why is that and is it possible to put a settimeout in the same function, calling the same function, i.e settimeout(showtime,1000) inside showtime function

Comment: You have to use `setTimeout` recursively or use `setInterval` once, otherwise the function will only be run once because nothing is calling it over and over again. Yes, it is possible to put a `setTimeout` inside `showTime - that's exactly what you're doing in your original code, and it works because the function is calling itself recursively, as explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the **setTimeout** is to set next count down for next second.

The use of **Innertext** is to set the time string to the element .

**Innertext** and **textcontent** are the same here.

Maybe you can try SetInterval as below to be more accurate:

```
function showTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours();// 0 - 23
    var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
    var session = "AM";

    if(h == 0){
        h = 12;
    }

    if(h > 12){
        h = h - 12;
        session = "PM";
    }

    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

    var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;

}

showTime(); 
setInterval(showTime, 1000);
```

Comment: Nope, that's wrong.  Pretty sure the function should be called every second, not once after one second.

Comment: I'm sorry for not changing the setTimeout to setInterval.
setTimeout as your code, however, not accurately run as you want - count per second - for long term because the time cost before setTimeout.